# What is the degree of linearity in the error propagated by Gradient Descent?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, gradient-descent

Neural Network is trained to learn a non-linear function, the more layers it has, the more is the quality of the prediction and the ability to match the real-world function correctly (lets leave aside overfitting for now).

Now, given that the concept of a derivative of a function (if it is not a line) is only defined at a single point , and worse than that, it is defined as a tangent line (so, its linear in essence) , and backpropagation uses this tangent line to project weight updates, does this mean that Gradient Descent is linear at its fundamental level ?

Then if Gradient Descent is using linearity to propagate back weight updates, imagine how big the error would be for non linear function? For example , you  have calculated that the weight number 129 of your network has to be decreased by 0.003412, but at that point with this new weight, the function might have already reversed its direction, and the real update for this weight must be a negative number!!! Isn't this the reason that our deep fully connected networks have such a difficulty to learn , because with more layers stacked up, the more non-linear the model becomes, and thus, the weight updates we propagate back to lower layers could be treated as "best guess" values instead of something that can be fully trusted?

I am correct in assuming that Gradient Descent is not calculating correct weight updates on each backwards step and that the only reason that the network eventually converges to required model is because these imprecisions are fixed in a loop (called epoch). So, if we use an analogy, Gradient Descent would be like navigating the World on a boat with maps developed with the assumption that the Earth is flat. With such maps, you can sail in near-by areas, but if you would travel around the world without knowing that the Earth is round you will never arrive to your destination, and that's exactly what we are experiencing when we train deep fully connected networks without making them converge.

This means, if Gradient Descent is broken in such a way, a correct Gradient Descent algorithm would only have to do SINGLE backwards step and update all the weights in one pass, giving the minimum error that is theoretically possible in 1 epoch .... I am right ?

So, my question basically is: is Gradient Descent a really broken algorithm or I am missing something?

Comment: What? Very confusing question to me. Are you saying that by the time you reach weight 129 after updating all weights till 128 the function value has already changed, or are you saying that the derivative changes value due to non linearity as it propagates backwards? Or you are saying none of the above.

Comment: @DuttaA, well there might be a condition that  after a change in this single weight (w129) by 0.003412, the Error will be totally different, and the function at that interval might be concave up now (after the change), while before this weight update gradient descent was assuming that the function is concave down. So, the weight update was incorrect

Comment: I mean we adjust weights to change the error, so the error will change and also the error surface will change (due to effect of other weights). Can't really understand your question though.

Comment: @DuttaA the question is easy: is it correct to change weights using a linear function when dealing with non-linear function? the real world function is non-linear , and it may not even be continous, and not differentiable at all

Comment: I mean second order derivatives exist which probably takes care of this, the learning rate is also responsible.

Comment: @DuttaA, well backpropagation uses first order derivatives of composite function. This is all based on the perpendicular line (tangent) to the function at some point. Weight updates assume this tangent is continuing in a linear way, and since the real world funciton is not linear, the error changes, and all this stuff doesn't work when networks are deep enough, becuase the depth of the network increases the non-linearity. Imagine that neural network (6 layers) is learning something similar to a cryptographic hash, you change single bit, and it all goes the other way. Butterfly Effect

Comment: That's what the learning rate is for.

Comment: @DuttaA, the learning rate is a softener on the amount of error. If Gradient Descent wouldn't be broken, no learning rate would be necessary.

Comment: I would not call it broken because it fails to do something. It was not designed for it, it is computationally efficient than other methods, which is what's important.

Comment: @DuttaA, It is computationally efficient for 2-3 layered networks. Then it becomes terribly inefficient and so far, Fully Connected Multi-layer Perceptron Networks haven't been built with more than 5 layers. The only progress that was made in last 2 decades is due to human-engineered convolutional layers, which can be stacked deeply because they don't have so many parameters in each kernel. But MLP networks can't be build for more than 5 layers. 20 years ago we had 50 times less computing power but we still can't train FC-MLP. Its not the hardware, its the algorithm.